# unfold function in R?

Tags: r

R has fold function `Reduce`. is there a corresponding unfold function? say, given a starting value and apply a function recursively to get an array? The for loop will do the job, just wondering if there is more R-like way for this. thanks,

An example, the code below plot lorenz attractor in 8 lines (mimic [F# Lorenz Attractor in 35 lines](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/07/lorenz-attractor.html). But the for loop looks ugly. Can we do better?

```
s <- 10; b <- 8/3; p <- 28
dt <- 0.003; n<-2000
x <- matrix(0,n,3); x[1,] <- c(10,0,20)
for (i in 2:n){
    x[i,] <- x[i-1,] + c(s * (x[i-1,2] - x[i-1,1]),x[i-1,1] * (p - x[i-1,3]) - x[i-1,2],x[i-1,1] * x[i-1,2] - b * x[i-1,3]) * dt
}
library(rgl)
plot3d(x,type= 'l',col = 'red')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
n<-2000
params <- list(s=10,b=8/3,p=28,dt=0.003)
X0 <- X <- c(x=10,y=0,z=20)


itfun <- function(X) {
  with(c(as.list(X),params),
       X + c(s*(y-x),x*(p-z)-y,x*y-b*z)*dt)
}
Xmat <- rbind(X0,t(replicate(n,X <<- itfun(X))))

library(rgl)
plot3d(Xmat,type= 'l',col = 'red')
```

**or** (incorporating answer from comments)

```
do.call(rbind, 
 Reduce(function(X, i) {
   with(c(params, as.list(X)), 
       X + c(s*(y-x),x*(p-z)-y,x*y-b*z)*dt)
   }, 
   seq(n), X, accumulate=TRUE)[-1])
```

PS how do you count lines? If you use enough semicolons you can do the whole thing on one line :-) I count 11 statements in your code

**edit**: was missing some parentheses in the `x` update

Comment: Note also `Reduce`'s `accumulate` argument. Eg, building on Ben's answer:

`do.call(rbind, Reduce(function(X, i) with(c(params, as.list(X)), X + c(s*y-x,x*(p-z)-y,x*y-b*z)*dt), 1:n, X, accum=T)[-1])`

Comment: @Ben Bolker - I don't get the same answer (or plot) with your code as the OP?!

Comment: @Tommy: good eye.  Fixed now.  should have been `s*(y-x)`, not `s*y-x`